# Permissions in Android 13 API 33 not working

Tags: c#, android, maui, android-permissions

I'm having trouble working with permissions for my Android app on .Net Maui for Android 13 API 33.
The popup that asks the user for permissions is not shown.
I've seen some posts on the internet that talk about the subject, but nothing so far has been able to solve my problem.
So I decided to share my code so you can help me solve the problem.

**AppShell Code**

```cs
private void AppShell_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessInit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}

private async Task ProcessInit()
{
    if (!RequestPermision.RequestStoragePermissionsBool())
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await RequestPermision.RequestStoragePermissions();
        });
    }
}
```

**Permissions Code**

**Nested Premises class for Android versions 12 and below**

```cs
public class ReadWriteStoragePermsLower12 : Permissions.BasePlatformPermission
{
    public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions =>
        new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
        {
            ("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", true),
            ("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", true),
            ("android.permission.INTERNET", true)
        }.ToArray();
}
```

**Nested Premises class for Android versions 13 and up**

```cs
public class ReadWriteStoragePerms : Permissions.BasePlatformPermission
{
    public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions =>
        new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)>
        {
            ("android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES", true),
            ("android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO", true),
            ("android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO", true),
            ("android.permission.INTERNET", true)
        }.ToArray();
}
```

**This is the class that checks the status of permissions and makes the request when permissions have not been granted**

```cs
public class RequestPermision
{
    private static IAppServices _services;

    public RequestPermision(IAppServices pServices)
    {
        _services = pServices;
    }

    public static async Task RequestStoragePermissions()
    {
        if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Android)
            return;

        var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

        if (DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13)
        {
            status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<ReadWriteStoragePerms>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                _services?.CallServiceListFolder();
                return;
            }

            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<ReadWriteStoragePerms>())
            {
                await AlertPermissionDenited();
            }

            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<ReadWriteStoragePerms>();

            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                await AlertPermissionDenited();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<ReadWriteStoragePermsLower12>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                _services?.CallServiceListFolder();
                return;
            }

            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<ReadWriteStoragePermsLower12>())
            {
                await AlertPermissionDenited();
            }

            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<ReadWriteStoragePermsLower12>();

            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                await AlertPermissionDenited();
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task AlertPermissionDenited()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Needs permissions", "Permissions are required for the app to access system folders and files to perform conversions!", "OK");
    }

    public static async Task<bool> RequestStoragePermissionsBool()
    {
        if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Android)
            return false;

        var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
        bool granted = false;

        if (DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13)
        {
            status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<ReadWriteStoragePerms>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                granted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<ReadWriteStoragePermsLower12>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                granted = true;
        }

        return granted;
    }
}
```

**The configuration of my AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="32" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: You are calling as async method without using await

Comment: FYI: Once you get this working (see answer(s)), you should handle the case where user DOESN'T give you permission. Test whether permission was successfully granted. Maybe set a static bool to true once it is.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You're calling some `async Task`s without `await`ing them
2. Because of 1., the `catch()`-clause of the try-catch-block will not be able to catch any exceptions thrown inside of the event handler, because the call will have run out of scope already
3. You're *(potentially)* offloading another `async Task` unnecessarily to the thread pool using `Task.Run()`
4. There is no need to throw a new exception, you can simply rethrow the current one in order to [preserve the original stack trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#the-throw-statement)

Change it to look like this:

```cs
private async void AppShell_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await ProcessInitAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex); //optional
        // just re-throw afterwards, if needed
        throw;
    }
}

private async Task ProcessInitAsync()
{
    if (!await RequestPermision.RequestStoragePermissionsBool())
    {
        await RequestPermision.RequestStoragePermissions();
    }
}
```

Apart from that, your code looks a bit complicated, but I cannot tell if there is another problem with it. If any exception is thrown, at least now your code will catch it for you to inspect it and take further action.